# Rewrite URL ASP.NET / Sharepoint

Tags: url, iis, sharepoint, web-config, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URLs from my website:

Existing URL:

```
http://mywebsite/_layouts/namespace/core/page.aspx
```

I want to get this URL:

```
http://mywebsite/core/page.aspx
```

I added this code to the web.config file on the `<system.webServer>` section but nothing has been changed :(

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Core Pages" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^core/([.]+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="_layouts/namespace/core/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your match url:

```
<match url="^core/(.+)" />
```